# Is $(-\infty, 0)$ the same size as $(0, \infty)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

A differential equations problem asked about the largest interval on which the solution was defined. The solution was defined except for $t=0$, which made me wonder whether the intervals $(-\infty, 0)$ and $(0, \infty)$ are the same size.

If these intervals are the same size, does that mean that $\mathbb{R}$ can be divided in half?

Comment: Ian's answer says what you need to know. As for the set-theoretic matter: 1) Those two intervals have the same length (= *Lebesgue measure* = $\infty$). 2) Any two intervals have the same *cardinality* $2^{\aleph_0}$. 3) $\Bbb R$, like any set of infinite cardinality (call it $\kappa$), can be partitioned into two (*even* $\kappa$) subsets of cardinality $\kappa$. 4) Technically, you did not give a partition of $\Bbb R$, but $\Bbb R\setminus \{0\}$. 5) $\Bbb R$ cannot be written as a union of finitely many disjoint open intervals.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're thinking too much. Here "the largest interval on which the solution is defined" means "the largest interval *containing the initial value* on which the solution is defined". It has nothing to do with lengths of intervals or cardinalities or anything: if the equation has a singularity at $t=0$ and nowhere else, and $t_0<0$, then the largest interval of definition is $(-\infty,0)$. Reverse that when $t_0>0$.

The tricky thing is that it can happen that the domain of the *formula* for the solution is bigger than the domain of the solution itself. For instance, $y'=-y^2,y(1)=1$ has a solution $y(t)=1/t$. Although $1/t$ is defined on $(-\infty,0) \cup (0,\infty)$, the solution to the IVP is defined only on $(0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 2):

They are the same size. Take $A,$ the set of all numbers $x \leq 0$ and $B,$ the set of all numbers $x \geq 0.$ Notice that for any element $x$ in $A,$ we can use the function $f(x) = -x$ to get to the corresponding element in $B.$ We can use the same function to go backwards. Since the sets are in **1-1 correspondence,** they are equal.

However, you cannot say that $(-\infty, 0)$ is half of $(-\infty, \infty),$ because both are of infinity size.

Comment: For completions sake, $(-\infty,0)$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are of the same size.

Answer (score 0):

In order to answer this question we need a precise definition of the size of a set.

There are several approaches to this, such as using cardinality or measure theory. We are going to stick to the first one.

In real life, sizes are made through comparisons. For example, we say that a house is 20 meters tall because its height corresponds to 20 times that of a bar of iridium which we have agreed its one meter tall.

We are going to use a similar procedure here, and define some standard sets to which we can compare the sizes of other sets.

We are going to say that two sets are of the same size if there exists a *correspondence* between them. A correspondence is defined as a one-to-one and onto function, which respectively mean that the function does not send two elements of its domain to the same element of the range; and that every element of its target set is assigned to an element of its domain.

Our definition agrees with our intuition in that $(0\ \infty)$ and $(-\infty\ 0)$ are the same size: consider the correspondence $f(x) = -x$.

Now comes the susprising part. It turns out that according to our definition, $(0\ \infty)$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are of the same size!

To see why this is the case, consider $f(x)=log(x)$. $f$ would be a correspondence which maps $(0\ \infty)$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

So the answer to your question is yes. $\mathbb{R}$ can be divided in half, but it turns out that each half is of the same size as the original set.

Comment: Your last sentence is a contradiction.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich No its not :) That's the magic of set theory.

Comment: No, it's the magic of imprecise language. If you say "$\mathbb{R}$ can be divided in half", then what do you refer to? The number of elements? This cannot be the case, as you have shown before. To decompose $\mathbb{R}$ in three subsets $\mathbb{R}_{<0}$, $\left\{ 0 \right\}$, and $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ is not the same as dividing something into two halves.

Comment: Sheesh, it was meant as an intuitive remark, not a technical one. For the record, if you want to strictly divide $\mathbb{R}$ in two disjoint sets each of the same size it is doable.  Adding a point to an already infinite set does not change its cardinality. Thus $[0\ \infty)$ is of the same size as $(0\ \infty)$. To see why this is the case, consider a correspondence which sends every whole number to its successor, and  0 to 1, while leaving everything else fixed. Thus $\mathbb{R}$ can be partitioned in $(-\infty\ 0)$ and $[0\ \infty)$, each of the same size.

Comment: "...it was meant as an intuitive remark, not a technical one". What does that mean? You proved (technically) that the intuitive view of $\mathbb{R}$, namely as something (such as a line) that can be divided into **halves** (line segments with **half the size** of the original line), is wrong. But then you say that the intuitive view is right?
Don't get me wrong: I only have problems with your last sentence. The rest is fine and would be worth a (+1).

Comment: My intuitive understanding of half a number $X$ is another number $Y$ such that $2Y=X$. According to every sensible kind of cardinal arithmetic, the cardinal $\aleph_1$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is such that $2\cdot \aleph_1= \aleph_1$, so we can say, in that sense, that each of the sets I partitioned $\mathbb{R}$ into are half the size of $\mathbb{R}$. I did no want to get too deep into the technical details since the answer was posed as introductory, but I am happy to solve any misunderstandings if necessary.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35253/discussion-between-bjorn-friedrich-and-jsevillamol).